# Nginx behind Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, django, gunicorn

I have an apache who is hosting websites
one is **000-default.conf** for **[www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com)**

another one is **domain2.conf** for **[www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com)**
and has a config like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ServerName activity.domain2.com
    ProxyPass / http://activity.domain2.com:8000
    ProxyPassReverse / http://activity.domain2.com:8000
</VirtualHost>
```

**domain2** is pointing http://activity.domain2.com:8000 that was served by Nginx

for Nginx the server is configured like this

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name activity.domain2.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /root/domain2;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
```

Everything is fine with **[www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com)**
Except, when I load **[www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com)**, only html file is served but static file request is error with code **502 proxy error**

How can I fix this?

## Update:

I decide to use nginx infront of Apache instead to fix the problem.
But still want to know the answer if possible.

Comment: A 5xx error usually has a corresponding entry in the error log with a clear error message. Check your logs.

Comment: Might be a missing slash after the "8000"s

Answer (score 1):

For starters: it looks like you miss a trailing slash

```
ProxyPass / http://activity.domain2.com:8000
                                            ^
                           add a "/" here _/
```

From the [manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass):

> *If the first argument ends with a trailing `/`, the second argument should also end with a trailing `/`, and vice versa. Otherwise, the resulting requests to the backend may miss some needed slashes and do not deliver the expected results.*

Second a proxy error is usually recorded in your (error) logs and like  with most errors, the log entry will usually be accompanied by more useful debugging information than what gets returned to a site visitor.  First check in the apache logs, but don't forget to also look at the logs for the nginx back-end server.